# sed/awk processing question for heavy 3GB csv database

Tags: regex, text, awk, sed

I’ve been given the responsibility of taking care of a few old LTO tape databases and thought it would be a nice opportunity to build a functional library and learn some bash scripting and text processing at the same time. The csv databases are about 30 million lines long at about 3GB each. I’ve become decently effective at using grep and regex for locating lines, but now I’d like to reformat the entire csv file with sed/awk for even faster processing. This is more difficult than I expected and was hoping some experts can point me in the right direction. The format of the csv database is as follows:

```
<START OF FILE>
AE19T1JA47 -

File Name,Directory Name,Size of File,Time Last Modified

Trash,,0,2013-12-20 13:38:04
RAW FOOTAGE,,0,2013-12-20 13:39:00
DAEDALUS - ARCHIVE - 122013,,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_HAFFLEN_PORTER_ROBINSON,DAED3 - ARCHIVE - 122013,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_JAPAN_SETTING_SUN_092413,DAED3 - ARCHIVE - 122013,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_YTMA_090713,DAED3 - ARCHIVE - 122013,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
Audio,DAED3 - ARCHIVE - 122013/STAR_BILLYB_PORTER_ROBINSON,0,2013-09-03 11:21:00
Footage,DAED3 - ARCHIVE - 122013/STAR_BILLYB_PORTER_ROBINSON,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
FWN_ASPERA_TEST_FTG,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
LANA_BRISK_REWSTO_WEEKEND_CASH_121813_RAW,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
LANA_STAR_WORLD_TURNT_LOST_WORLDS_121713_RAW,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
CZECH_PILOTS_ARCHIVAL,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_CAND_ELVY_121713_RAW,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_NEWS_PROMOS_PETE_122013_RAW,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
STAR_PODCAST_STEVE_Q_NG_121913_RAW,RAW FOOTAGE,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
A242_C035_0101MR.RDC,RAW FOOTAGE/FWN_ASPERA_TEST_FTG,0,2013-12-20 13:40:00
md5,RAW FOOTAGE/FWN_FTP_TEST_FTG/A242_C035_0101MR.RDC,0,2013-08-30 08:19:00
MVI_9292.THM,RAW FOOTAGE/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_PROMO_121613_RAW/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_BONES_PROMO_121613_A_01/DCIM/100EOS7D,18687,2013-12-13 17:16:00
._MVI_9293.MOV,RAW FOOTAGE/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_PROMO_121613_RAW/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_BONES_PROMO_121613_A_01/DCIM/100EOS7D,4096,2013-12-20 14:43:00
MVI_9286.THM,RAW FOOTAGE/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_PROMO_121613_RAW/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_BONES_PROMO_121613_A_01/DCIM/100EOS7D,11570,2013-12-13 17:06:00
._MVI_9294.THM,RAW FOOTAGE/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_PROMO_121613_RAW/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_BONES_PROMO_121613_A_01/DCIM/100EOS7D,4096,2013-12-20 14:43:00
MVI_9286.MOV,RAW FOOTAGE/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_PROMO_121613_RAW/STAR_CRANK_ELVY_BONES_PROMO_121613_A_01/DCIM/100EOS7D,387269573,2013-12-13 17:06:00
._.DS_Store,,4096,2013-12-21 16:01:00
.DS_Store,,6148,2013-12-21 16:01:00


AE19T1ML3W -

File Name,Directory Name,Size of File,Time Last Modified

Trash,,0,2013-12-21 16:21:39
DRIVE BACKUPS,,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
STAR_00112_500GB_BOMBU_REELS,DRIVE BACKUPS,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,DRIVE BACKUPS,0,2013-12-21 16:26:00
STAR_01113_1TB_southy_Freeski,DRIVE BACKUPS,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
STAR 1 TB 31,DRIVE BACKUPS,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
Media,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_00112_500GB_BOMBU_REELS,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
V_BOMBU_ALLVERSIONS_20131121,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_00112_500GB_BOMBU_REELS/Media,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
tabsz_LOREAL_DELIVERY_082213,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
LANA_SIZZLE_REEL_082213,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
43_STAR SWSW,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
2013-03-16.bbr,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
ADDITIONAL_tabsz_FILES,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
Autosave Vault,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00
WADU_SATURDAY,DRIVE BACKUPS/STAR_LANACannesGabby_00106,0,2013-12-21 16:27:00


<END OF FILE>
```

Broken down structurally, each csv database looks like this:

```
<START OF FILE>
<LTO TAPE NAME><SPACE><DASH>
<NEWLINE>
<TOC LEGEND>
<NEWLINE>
<CONTENTS OF TAPE ABOVE>
<NEWLINE>
<NEWLINE>
<NAME OF NEXT LTO TAPE><SPACE><DASH>
<NEWLINE>
<TOC LEGEND>
<NEWLINE>
<CONTENTS OF TAPE ABOVE>
<NEWLINE>
<NEWLINE>
<END OF FILE>
```

I'd like to truncate the entire database by taking the LTO tape name and appending it to the end of the line of its contents seperated by a comma instead, allowing me to more easily see which tape each file is on. Essentially, I'd like to take the structure above, and reformat it into this:

```
<START OF FILE>
<TOC LEGEND>
<CONTENTS OF TAPE>,<RESPECTIVE TAPE NAME>
<CONTENTS OF TAPE...>,<RESEPCTIVE TAPE NAME>
...
<END OF FILE>
```

Comment: Reduce your example to a [mcve] so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{
 {if (/^[A-Z0-9]* -$/)
  {split($1,name," ")}
 else if (NF == 4 && $4 != "Time Last Modified")
  {print $0","name[1]}}}' tape.txt
```

This might work if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.  This will attempt to find the name of the tape by using a regex.  If it finds something that matches the regex, it will split on the space to simply get the name.  It will then look for any line that has 4 fields that doesn't have "Time Last Modified" for the 4th field, it then prints the line out and appends the first value of the name array on the end.

Comment: This was both inspiring and functional